# Преобразование индекса к типу bool

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Хочу заполнить новый столбец `DataFrame` значениями, рассчитанными на основе индекса по простому алгоритму: если индекс - целое число, то `False`, в противном случае `True`, т.е. выходное поле типа `bool`.
Изначально индекс имеет тип float64:

```
Float64Index([39.5, 40.5, 41.5, 43.5, 46.5, 47.5], dtype='float64', name='size_h')
```

Применяю формулу:

```
group.index.map(lambda x: bool(x % 1))
```

В итоге результирующий индекс приобретает тип `object`:

```
Index([True, True, True, True, True, True], dtype='object', name='size_h')
```

Но мне нужен именно логический тип. При этом по непонятной причине не срабатывает функция `astype`:

```
group.index.map(lambda x: bool(x % 1)).astype('bool')

Index([True, True, True, True, True, True], dtype='object', name='size_h')
```

Отсюда у пытливого ума возникает два связанных вопроса:
1. Почему после применения функции тип индекса изменился на `object`, хотя очевидно, что он `bool`?
2. Почему не отрабатывает функция `astype` и тип все равно остается `object`?

Работает только следующая конфигурация:

```
group['flag'] = group.index.map(lambda x: bool(x % 1))
group['flag'] = group['flag'].astype('bool')
```

Но из эстетических соображений и морального удовлетворения хочется понять почему не отрабатывает вышеописанный вариант.

Спасибо!

Comment: не могли бы вы добавить к примеру кода используемые модули и то как вы их подключаете.Понятно -  pandas, что еще?

Comment: я думаю, вам следует использовать np.bool_  в вашей формуле

Comment: Собственно кроме pandas и numpy больше ничего не подключаю.  
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np
 - собственно и все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [161]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col':np.random.randint(10, size=6)}, index=[39, 40.5, 41.5, 43, 46.5, 47])

In [162]: df
Out[162]:
      col
39.0    2
40.5    5
41.5    3
43.0    9
46.5    4
47.0    0
```

решение:

```
In [167]: df['new'] = df.index.astype(int) != df.index
```

результат:

```
In [168]: df
Out[168]:
      col    new
39.0    2  False
40.5    5   True
41.5    3   True
43.0    9  False
46.5    4   True
47.0    0  False
```